# python3 issues after homebrew based upgrade

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, homebrew

I just updated my python3 using homebrew and my python3 was messed up badly. I followed the instructions on other threads and was able to cleanly install python3 but some linking still exists that I am unable to figure out.

**Problem:**
python3 -version
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python
Referenced from: /Users/abcd/.ansible/py3/bin/python3
Reason: image not found
zsh: abort      python3 -version

Python paths:

abcd@abcd-ltm Cellar % which python
/Users/abcd/.ansible/py3/bin/python

abcd@abcd-ltm Cellar % which python3
/Users/abcd/.ansible/py3/bin/python3

echo $PATH:

/Users/abcd/.ansible:/Users/abcd/.ansible/py3/bin:/Users/abcd/.ansible/bin:/Users/abcd/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/abcd/.ansible:/Library/Apple/usr/bin

I dont know from where it is still refering and getting this error at any python3 command
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/Cellar/python/3.6.5_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Python

I can confirm there is no folder named python inside /usr/local/Cellar/. There is one newly created python@3.8 though which should be correct. Any pointers how I can find where is it picking up the incorrect python path and how I can fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears you have an ansible installation that built a virtualenv associated with the Python that was upgraded in Homebrew. You should rebuild those virtualenvs or remove them from your `PATH` if you don't need them.